# in MySQL, revoke a privilege after granting a general privilege

Tags: mysql, privileges

Using standard SQL - have have done this repeatedly in PosgresQL and Oracle - I wish to grant a SELECT to all tables in schema1 *except* `secret` to user1

```
grant select on schema1.* to user1;
revoke select on schema1.users from user1;
```

Received error:

```
ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user1' on host '%' on table 'secret'
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Evidently this is standard MySQL behavior!!

Makes it easier to understand the lack of security sophistication in apps using MySQL - to set up correct user security in MySQL is insanely difficult.

Comment: You should grant SELECT privileges for each table, table by table.

Comment: Are you sure?  ANSI standard says what I am doing is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing. MySQL doesn't expand the `schema1.*` wildcard to the individual tables, nor does it store "exceptions". The permissions tables store the granted permissions. Therefore, since you didn't actually grant anything on `schema1.users`, there's nothing for MySQL to revoke. It just comes down to how MySQL handles permissions.

Comment: so GRANT/REVOKE in MySQL is _not_ ANSI standard?

Comment: @ccyoung Perhaps. I'm not intimately familiar with the standard. I know there are several other places where MySQL deviates, so it wouldn't surprise me. I'd suggest opening a bug with the MySQL team (it's likely one already exists), but would also suggest not putting off major life decisions until it's addressed. We're talking about core MySQL that's been in place for many years (centuries in Internet time). Chances of that ever being changed are slim to none.